# Mysql strip time component from datetime

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I need to do a date comparison in Mysql without taking into account the time component i.e. i need to convert '2008-11-05 14:30:00' to '2008-11-05'

Currently i am doing this:

```
SELECT from_days(to_days(my_date))
```

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Yes, use the [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
SELECT date(my_date)
```

Comment: This is the one. Thanks. Last on the list of Answers for some reason.

Answer (score 25):

`select date(somedate)` is the most common.

If you need to accommodate other formats, you can use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_date, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: The DATE_FORMAT is very useful for extracting the year component only for example. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL you use the TRUNC() function, but I'm not seeing it for MySQL.  From my brief Googling, it looks like you'll need to cast your DATETIME value to be just DATE.

```
date_col = CAST(NOW() AS DATE)
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: `date_trunc()` (not `trunc()`)  wouldn't actually *remove* the time part in Postgres. It would merely set it to `00:00:00` which is something different.

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple way of doing it `date("d F Y",strtotime($row['date']))` where `$row['date']` comes from your query

Answer (score -5):

You could use `ToShortDateString();`

Comment: Isn't that a C# function? The question is after a MySQL solution

Comment: It's C# and actually it does not remove the timestamp: Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent short date string representation.