# I have a date/time stamp field, where I need to pull records just by date

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a date/time stamp field, where I need to pull records just by date.

Example: All data were records are >= '01/01/2016'.

The data in the field is store in the following format '9/5/2012 7:34:59 AM'

I have tried the following but either I get an error or bad results:

- `where to_char(start_time) > '01/01/2016'`  (still gives 2012 records)
- `where trunc(start_time) > '01/01/2016'`   (Error: Not a valid month)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267721/mysql-strip-time-component-from-datetime

Comment: to_char and trunc are from Oracle...you sure you're using MySQL?

Comment: Is your date/time stamp field of `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type, or is it `VARCHAR2` or `NUMBER`? The best way to know is to run the `DESCRIBE` command: `DESCRIBE <table_name>`. This will give you the names AND DATA TYPES of all the columns in your table.

Answer (score 1):

In  mysql you should use

this is in string canonical format

```
select * from my_table 
where start_time > '2016/01/01'
```

or

or converting by str_to_date using proper format

```
select * from my_table 
where start_time > str_to_date('01/01/2016', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_date` to convert the string to date and then do the comparison.

Try this:

```
where start_time >= to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked.  I able to get the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle (and perhaps other database products) you can use the ANSI date literal, as shown below. You could also use `to_date()`, but the benefit of the ANSI date literal is that it doesn't require a function call. (Function calls are overhead which consumes time and resources, although calling `to_date()` just once is not a concern.)

```
... where start_time >= date '2016-01-01'
```

Note that in the ANSI standard date literal, the date **must** be in the exact format YYYY-MM-DD (with dashes and not with slashes or any other separators), since the ANSI date literal does **not** take a format model.