# C# Day Midnight to timestamp

Tags: c#, timestamp

I would like to create a time stamp of the day in C#** for MySql.

I have to get the current time stamp: `1511225840 (2017-11-21 01:58:14)` and convert to: `1511218800 (2017-11-21 00:00:00)`

How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql strip time component from datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267721/mysql-strip-time-component-from-datetime)

Comment: You want to do this in C#? You can use take Date part of the DateTime variable to store in the db. Like `var mydate = selectedDate.Date;`

Comment: If you're worried about creating formatted time strings for an sql statement, you're doing it wrong. Parameterized queries or go home.