# Removing time from a datetime field in a select query

Tags: php, sql-server

I have the following SQL query to use on my website and I want to remove the time from the datetime column 'Date_Required' when the resulting table is displayed:

```
$query = "SELECT Job_No, Sub_No, Visit_Status, Engineer, CAST(Date_Required AS DATE) FROM dbo.VSMF_SERVICE_VISITS WHERE Visit_Status = 'O' and Engineer='*AY' and Date_Required >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' ORDER BY Date_Required DESC";
```

So it's displayed as "Jan 01 2018" instead of "Jan 01 2018 12:00:00:000PM"

The query is in a PHP file.

Comment: do this in the presentation layer, not in the database layer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I'm doing this in a PHP file so I don't think that would work?

Comment: All I know about PHP is it's name. Can't help there, sorry.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/267732/5407848](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267732/5407848)

Comment: @Accountantم - They just show selecting one column not multiple columns like mine.

Comment: You can specify the fields  to be selected one by one and use `CAST(myDatetimeCol AS Date)` to convert the datetime field into date. It's generally a bad practice anyway using `*` in `SELECT` clause.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice sql-server. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222075/sql-datetime-format-to-date-only)

Comment: I've edited my query and no results are displayed for the date column now.

Comment: try to use DATE() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$query = "SELECT CAST(Date_Required AS DATE) as Date_Required FROM dbo.VSMF_SERVICE_VISITS WHERE Visit_Status = 'O' and Engineer='*AY' and Date_Required >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' ORDER BY Date_Required DESC";
```

I hope this will work for you. If you want to select all the columns in the table then mention them in the select statement one by one like this

```
SELECT id, name, CAST(Date_Required AS DATE) as Date_Required from ...
```

using * will be more tricky.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I get no results when I run that query.

Comment: was there any exception ?

Comment: okay try this one. $query = "SELECT DATE(\`Date_Required\`) as Date_required FROM dbo.VSMF_SERVICE_VISITS WHERE Visit_Status = 'O' and Engineer='*AY' and Date_Required >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' ORDER BY Date_Required DESC";

Comment: I think problem is in some single quote. Otherwise this query is working fine in phpmyadmin sql editor.

Comment: No that doesn't work either, blank again with no exception.

Comment: You can try this `DATE(\`Date_Required\`)` technique on a simple table in your sql editor and than i think you can better understand how to make it work in your current problem.

Comment: okay once more try removing backticks like this. `$query = "SELECT DATE(Date_Required) as Date_required FROM dbo.VSMF_SERVICE_VISITS WHERE Visit_Status = 'O' and Engineer='*AY' and Date_Required >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' ORDER BY Date_Required DESC";`

Comment: I found the error, it says "DATE is not a recognised built in function name."

Comment: Okay try this one. `CAST(Date_Required AS DATE)` instead of `DATE(Date_Required) as Date_required`. I never worked on sql server but you can try this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166224/discussion-between-ross-h-and-noman-tufail).

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to do this in SQL, then have a read of this post (which it took me a couple of seconds to find):

[Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: I'm struggling with selecting multiple columns and having multiple where conditions. The link you gave only shows one select and no where conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with PHP you have several options, cutting the first 10 chars of the string by [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or using the powerful [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php
$dateTime = "2018-03-05 01:30:00";

echo substr($dateTime, 0 , 10);// option 1 
echo "\n";
$dateTimeObj = new DateTime($dateTime);// option 2 
echo $dateTimeObj->format("Y-m-d");
```

this outputs

> 2018-03-05
>
> 2018-03-05

[live demo](https://eval.in/966563)

Comment: Thank you, but the date is a variable from an SQL Server database not a hardcoded date.

Comment: the `$dateTime` is for demonstration. Replace it with your actual value at the presentation layer (right before you put it in the HTML)