# What do I need to add to my code to change the date format

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

What do I need to add to my code to change the date format from 'DD-MM-YYYY HH: MM: SS' to 'DD-MM-YYYY'

This is what I get:

```
rog_date             total_grand
2021-09-29 00:00:00     150
```

code:

`SELECT rog_date, SUM(garnitura) AS total_grand  FROM G0003 GROUP BY date(rog_date)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267721/mysql-strip-time-component-from-datetime

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(rog_date, '%d-%m-%Y');`

Try it here: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_date_format

Comment: if you are grouping by date(rog_date), you should be selecting that too.  newer versions of mysql will default to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode and give an error if you just select rog_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

> ```
> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2021-09-29 00:00:00',('%d.%m.%Y')) as 'date', 150 as 'Granbt total'
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | Granbt total
> :--------- | -----------:
> 29.09.2021 |          150
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ec8898af2fa40fda7ca1c8f7e120c0b)*

Comment: Thank you for the help! The final solution for me was this: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(rog_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as 'rog_date', SUM(garnitura) AS total_grand FROM G0003 GROUP BY date(rog_date)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(rog_date,'%Y-%m-%d') as date , SUM(garnitura) AS total_grand  FROM G0003 GROUP BY date